# How to import latitude and longitude data from a csv into a point data type column in MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, import, geolocation

I am trying to migrate location data from SQL Server to MySQL. In order to do so, I exported location data to a CSV file using c# in the following format

```
5;1442891783;POINT(43.7070275,-79.3972633);2;351;0;1442891785
5;1442891846;POINT(43.7071198,-79.3972495);2;353;0;1442891848
```

When I tried to import a CSV file in MySQL I am getting the following error

**Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field**

I can't change the MySQL schema because this schema is using by other clients.

Here is the portion of the schema

```
  `col1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `col2` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `location` point NOT NULL,
  `col3` float NOT NULL,
  `col4` float NOT NULL,
  `col5` float NOT NULL,
  `col6` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`col1`,`col2`),
  SPATIAL KEY `location` (`location`),
  KEY `col2` (`col2`)
```

I am an MS SQL guy, don't know much about MySQL.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Use [Input Preprocessing](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html#load-data-input-preprocessing). Something like

```sql
LOAD DATA INFILE 'filename.ext'
INTO TABLE tablename
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ';'
( col1,
  col2,
  @location,
  col3,
  col4,
  col5,
  col6 )
SET location = ST_GeometryFromText(@location)
```